# How was it calculated that Dream cheated on his Minecraft v1.16 glitchless speedrun?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, gaming-history, speedrun

The speedrunner Dream has recently been accused of cheating in his Minecraft Java v1.16 glitchless speedrun.

How did the Minecraft Java speedrunning mods calculate if Dream cheated?

Answer (score 71):

### The Short Summarized Answer

[These are the relevant facts](https://www.reddit.com/r/SubredditDrama/comments/kitba0/rstatistics_weigh_into_the_dream_cheating_debacle/ggsun1b/).

> These were drop rates for two items important to the speedrun attempts over the course of six livestreams.
>
> Ender pearls are obtained **4.7**% of the time. Out of *262* rolls they were obtained *42* times.
>
> Blaze rods are obtained **50%** of the time. Out of *305* rolls the were obtained *211* times.
>
> The probability of being at least this lucky in each case can be modelled by a binomial distribution.
>
> For the ender pearls this probability is *0.00000000000565319*.
>
> For the blaze rods this probability is *0.00000000000879143*.
>
> These probabilities are independent so the chances of both occurring is their product, *0.000000000000000000000049699624* or **1 in 20 sextillion**.
>
> You can do some adjustments for biases but they don't even come close to reaching a reasonable probability.

### The Long In-Depth Answer

This video sums up the decision behind the mod's actions, based on a [paper made studying](https://mcspeedrun.com/dream.pdf) how incredibly statistically unlikely his run ended up being. You can either watch the video or read the paper to understand the reasoning behind their actions.

#### Did Dream cheat?

Yes, he's actually admitted to doing so.  [Here's the relevant clicky.](https://www.ginx.tv/en/minecraft/dream-finally-admits-to-cheating-in-minecraft-speedrun) In a recently deleted tweet he posted a confession of sorts that revealed he had "inadvertently" used mods to enhance the drop rate of ender pearls and blaze rods.

[image]

You can find an [archived version of his confession here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210530115917/https://pastebin.com/7nfjLwi3). The relevant paragraph in regards to cheating in his run:

[image]

> After considering this, **I ended up finding out that I HAD actually been using a disallowed modification during ~6 of my live streams on Twitch**. At the time we were just starting to record videos on 1.16 and we had just hired a developer to help with coding mods for videos because me and George had no experience with mods only plugins. One of the mods that they were working on was an overall recording mod, that I have used in every video (with updates and improvements) since around the speedrun controversy.

Comment: +1 Good Answer. Karl Jobsts [video on this subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f8TlTaTHgzo) is worth watching as well.

Comment: Here is an actual quote from Dream "admitting" he cheated: *"At this point I was lost, and I was fairly confused about the whole thing. Wondering what the other options were and exploring the possibilities. as much as I was confident that I didn't cheat, I had never explored the option that I possibly did."*

Comment: Matt Parker made a good video as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ko3TdPy0TU

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft That quote doesn't really say anything and there are parts of his statement where he did actually admit things. He did admit that "I ended up finding out that I HAD actually been using a disallowed modification..." and he goes on to explain that it increased spawn/drop rates and how he wasn't aware of it. This is certainly an admission that he had an unfair advantage due to game mods, but whether it's an admission of "cheating" is probably a matter of semantics.

Comment: @NotThatGuy The usual definition of "cheating" in a game or sport is not following the rules or doing something disallowed by the rules. He admits that he used a modification disallowed by the rules. This is why many articles about this issue describe him as "cheating unknowningly" or "accidentally cheating".

Comment: @NotThatGuy Dream cleared his mod folder before submitting it to the mods. He admitted doing so. From that point on, _at least_, he was aware that he used modifications of some sort. That he "wasn't aware" of what those mods did is... strange, to say the least.

Comment: ...especially that he specifically commissioned the custom mod to modify these drop rates "to make his videos more interesting." Did he forget he paid money to have a mod made that did just what the moderators accused him of?

Comment: @SF. he forgot that it was affecting the speedrun. He already used the mod and mentioned it publicly before. But he, in his statement, thought that it wasn't affecting his speedrun.

Comment: @justhalf I don't buy the "oops I forgot I was cheating". When it's plainly obvious and Dream went out of his way to hire a Harvard astrophysicist to defend himself all the while leveraging his giant fanbase against the speedrunning mods which he claimed was a witchhunt, it's pretty clear that this response is a way to tone down the severity of what he actually did.

Comment: Hm, I see his response as a plausible alternative to the root cause (where he also described why he hired the astrophysicist), and not something that is simply cooked up, especially with his deleting his defense video. Perhaps even someone can do an comparative analysis with what an actual intentional cheater would have written and compare it with Dream's notes, and would have found that Dream's notes do not bear the characteristics of an intentional cheater. Anyway, I'm glad that it's resolved and he is taking responsibility, and people are cool again.

Comment: @justhalf Then why, when requested to provide the game files used in the speedrun, he removed the mod from the files sent? If he believed the mod was irrelevant, he had no reason to remove it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process and rules of submitting speedrun, so no comment on that specific action. If it were anything similar to any other kinds of submission to a contest, I too would clear irrelevant folders to reduce clutter (e.g., in software engineering, cleaning out files that were used in the past when trying different ideas when trying to submit a clean state)

Comment: @justhalf those aren't irrelevant folders, however. Moderatorss ask those folders because it is easy to put mods that change details in the game to make it easier to pull off a speedrun. Those are _proof_ that you did or didn't cheat. More so, if you **aren't cheating**, those folders will most likely be empty by default or contain speed-run approved mods, like timers or stuff like that. There is very little reason to clear a mod folder at all, more so when it is standard procedure to check those files in case of a cheating situation.